# in linux, how to compute the md5 of several files at once, and put the output in a text file?

Tags: linux, gzip, md5sum

I have many files in mypath that look like `file_01.gz`, `file_02.gz`, etc

I would like to compute the md5 `checksums` for each of them, and store the output in a text file with something like

```
filename  md5
file01    fjiroeghreio
```

Is that possible on linux?

Many thanks!

Comment: `md5sum file01 > output.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
md5sum file*.gz > output.txt
```

Output file is space separated, without header

Answer (score 1):

Linux already has a tool called md5sum, so all you need to do is call it for every file you want. In the approach below you get the default format of the md5sum tool, "SUM NAME", one per line for each file found. By using the double redirect (>>) each call will append to the bottom of the output file, sums.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.gz; do
    md5sum "$f" >> sums.txt
done
```

The above is illustrative only, you should probably check for the pre-existence of the output file, deal with errors etc.

There's lots of ways of doing this, so it all depends on further requirements. Must the format be of the form you state, must it recurse directories etc.?

Comment: You should always quote file names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [shell filename expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_08):

```
md5sum *.gz > file
```